# Powershell Custom Objects: How To Acess NoteProperty of collected result

Tags: powershell, custom-object, pscustomobject

Reading through an Article about custom Objects:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730946.aspx

I wonder why i get a result for the individual entry: e.g $objAverage.Name

while by  $colAverages.Name nothing is returened.
Although with Get-Member both show the [System.Object] NoteProperty Name

I would expect returning the all Names of my resultset in $colAverages.

Code of the article:
C:\Temp\base.txt

```
Name,AtBats,Hits
Ken Myer,43,13
Pilar Ackerman,28,11
Jonathan Haas,37,17
Syed Abbas,41,20
Luisa Cazzaniga,22,6
Andrew Cencini,35,11
Baris Cetinok,19,4
```

Powershell:

```
$colAverages = @()

$colStats =Import-Csv C:\Temp\base.txt

foreach ($objBatter in $colStats)
  {
    $objAverage = New-Object System.Object
    $objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $objBatter.Name
    $objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name BattingAverage -value ("{0:N3}" -f ([int] $objBatter.Hits / $objBatter.AtBats))
    $colAverages += $objAverage
  }

$colAverages | Sort-Object BattingAverage -descending
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $colAverages[0].name

```
for ($i=0 ; $i -le $colAverages.Length ; $i++)
{
  $colAverages[$i].name
}
```

Or

```
foreach ($a in $colAverages)
{
  $a.name
}
```

---------- EDIT----------

```
PS C:\> $colAverages.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                     BaseType                                                
-------- -------- ----                     --------                                                
True     True     Object[]                 System.Array                                            


PS C:\> $objAverage.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                     BaseType                                                
-------- -------- ----                     --------
True     True     Oject
```

Comment: OK, colAveragesis an Array,  $objAverage is not. But why produces a Get-Member the same result? I thought i'd see a difference betwen the two objects...